# handle enter key in soft keyboard in custom Layout

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I created a RelativeLayout with some buttons on it and pass it to view of InputMethodService
i handle letter buttons in OnClickListener() of buttons with InputConnection.commitText()
but how can i handle enter button in different types like search, send, done, go, next and return ??
I do not use KeyboarView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When those buttons are pressed, the soft keyboard calls `InputConnection.performEditorAction(int action)`.  So when you want to send a GO, NEXT, etc just call that function.  If you want to send an enter, just commit a newline.